# JFrame size affecting JButton size but only vertically?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jbutton

I am confused about how JFrame extends the JButton vertically to match JFrame min size but not horizontally. I would like for it to not extend in either direction and know why it extends or doesn't.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class somestring {
    public static void main(String []args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension max = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
        frame.setSize(max);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton s = new JButton("generate somestring");
        s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        content.add(s, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused about how JFrame extends the JButton vertically to match JFrame min size but not horizontally.

```
content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
...
content.add(s, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

The default layout manager of the content pane of the frame is the `BorderLayout`, so the above is unnecessary.

In any case, the reason it extend vertically is because that is the rule of the `BorderLayout` when you add a component to the `WEST`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The section on the `BorderLayout` will explain the rules for adding components to the `WEST`.

> I would like for it to not extend in either direction

Then you need to use a different layout manager.

For example you could use a `FlowLayout`. The button will be centered at the top of the frame.

Or you could use a `GridBagLayout` (with the default GridBagConstraints). The button will be centered both horizontally and vertically.

```
frame.pack();
frame.setResizable(false);
```

You should set the resizable property BEFORE invoking pack().

```
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
frame.setSize(max);
```

Not sure why you are setting the minimum size and invoking setSize(). If you want the button to be displayed at its preferred size, then just invoke pack().

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't notice the properties of borderlayout caused this.